# Create table column with the number of a particular column with php

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, html-table

I have an array of data and want to display it on a table, but the columns that appear in the table according to the number of array data, how to make 12 column array default but the number remains on the database. suppose there are 2 data appear in the table but there are a number of columns 12...?

Models

```
function get_id($id) {
    $this->db->where('my_id', $id);
    $get_data = $this->db->get('mytable');
    if ($get_data->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($get_data->result() as $data) {
            $my_result[] = $data;
        }
        return $my_result;
    }
}
```

Controllers

```
public function myControllers() {
    $id =  $this->uri->segment(4);
    $data=array('detail'    => $this->mymodels->get_id($id));
    $this->load->view('layout/wrapper', $data);
}
```

Views

```
<table>
    <thead> 
        <tr>
            <td>No</td>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Class</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>  
    <tbody> 
    <?php
        $no = 1;
        foreach ($detail as $row) {         
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>'.$no.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$row->id.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$row->name.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$row->class.'</td>';
            echo '</tr>';

            $no++;
        }           
    ?>
    </tbody>      
</table>
```

I expected as this example

```
NO  | ID  | NAME | ClASS |
____|____ |______|_______|
 1  | 001 | Paul |    x  |
 2  |     |      |       |
 3  |     |      |       |
 4  |     |      |       |
to 12
```

Comment: Column or row.?

Comment: @noufalcep columns and default row 12, although there are only four columns and rows of data there are 12

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question, you want to have a default of 12 rows in your table, even if only 2 rows are filled with data.

What about adding a while loop after your foreach loop that continues incrementing your counter and adding rows until your counter reaches 12?

```
while ($no <= 12) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$no.'</td>';
    echo '<td></td>';
    echo '<td></td>';
    echo '<td></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    $no++;
}
```

Comment: yes correct its default row and column 12, though there are 2 or 5 columns and rows of data remain 12, ok I'll try her

Comment: after I try to add a script `foreach ($ data_pemeliharan as $ row) while ($ No. <= 12) {` No column number 12 but the data being the same of all, it should even though there are only 2 data, 10 other columns there is no data

Comment: So all 12 rows are there but they don't have the numbers in the column? add `' . $no . '` in the first `<td>` tag. I've edited my original answer to include this.

Comment: Your example script generate `ID Name class` 12 column with the same values, I expect if I have one of data, the number of fixed columns 12 only one there is data that appear in the table that the other columns blank columns